# Is $(B_t^2 - t^2)_{t\geq 0}$ a local martingale?

Tags: brownian-motion, local-martingales

Let $B$ be a standard $\mathbb{R}$-valued Brownian motion. It is very easy to show that $(B_t^2 - t^2)_{t\geq 0}$ is not a martingale by checking the martingale condition. First, note that $(B_t^2 - t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale. Using the martingale condition of $(B_t^2 - t)_{t\geq 0}$ yields:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}\left[B_t^2 - t^2\vert\mathcal{F}_s\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[B_t^2 - t\vert\mathcal{F}_s\right] + t - t^2 = B_s^2 - s + t - t^2 \overset{!}{=} B_s^2 - s^2\\
&\Leftrightarrow t - t^2 = s - s^2
\end{align*}
The last equation is not always true (e.g. take $s=1$ and $t=2$) and thus $(B_t^2 - t^2)_{t\geq 0}$ is not a martingale. However, I have no clue how to investigate if $(B_t^2 - t^2)_{t\geq 0}$ is a local martingale.

Comment: Clearly $(B_t^2 - t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a martingale. Hence, for any sequence of stopping times $T_n \to \infty$, the stopped process $X_t = B^2_{t \wedge T_n} - (t \wedge T_n)$ is a martingale. Hence, in order for $(B_t^2 - t^2)_{t \ge 0}$ to be a local martingale, we would in particular need to have $\mathbb E[ (t \wedge T_n) - (t\wedge T_n)^2 ] = 0$ for any $t \in (0,1)$. But $s - s^2 \ge 0$ for $s \in (0,1)$ and hence the latter would imply $t \wedge T_n = (t \wedge T_n)^2$ a.s., i.e. $T_n = 0$ a.s. due to $t \in (0,1)$, which is a contradiction with $T_n \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Presage Thank you. Feel free to write your comment as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the process $(B_t^2 - t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a martingale. This implies (by Doob's Theorem) that for any finite stopping time $\tau$, the stopped process $X_t = (B_{t \wedge \tau}^2 - t\wedge \tau)_{t \ge 0}$ is a martingale.

In order for $(B_t^2 - t^2)$ to be a local martingale, we would in particular need the existence of stopping time $\tau$ such that $(B_{t \wedge \tau}^2 - (t \wedge \tau)^2 )_{t \ge 0}$ is a martingale. But if this process is a martingale, then for any $t \ge 0$, $$ 0 = \mathbb E[B_{t \wedge \tau}^2 - (t \wedge \tau)^2] = \mathbb E[t \wedge \tau - (t \wedge \tau)^2].$$ Since $s - s^2 \ge 0$ for $s \in (0,1)$ we see the latter for $t \in (0,1)$ implies $t \wedge \tau = (t \wedge \tau)^2$ almost surely, i.e., $\tau = 0$ almost surely due to $t \in (0,1)$.

This shows that there cannot exist a sequence of stopping times $T_n \to +\infty$ such that $(B_{t \wedge T_n}^2 - (t \wedge T_n)^2)_{t \ge 0}$ are martingales for any $n$.

Comment: I get that $\mathbb{E}\left[B_t^2\right]=t$, but I am unsure if $\mathbb{E}\left[B_{t\land\tau}^2\right]=t\land\tau$ since $t\land\tau$ is not a real number strictly speaking.

Comment: Of course not, it is crucial that $t \wedge \tau$ is under expectation, i.e. I've used $\mathbb E[B_{t \wedge \tau}^2 - (t \wedge \tau)] = 0$ due to $(B_t^2 - t)_{t \ge 0}$ being zero mean martingale and Doob's theorem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still struggle to follow. You assumed $\tau$ to be finite (?) in order to apply [Doob's optional sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem). If by finite you mean "$\tau$ is bounded", then you just showed the non-existence of a reducing sequence of bounded stopping times. If by finite you mean "$\tau$ has finite expectation", then you shouldn't be able to apply Doob's theorem immediately. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: I assumed $\tau$ to be any finite stopping time. You are right with your doubts, but please note that here we use Doob's Theorem not to $\tau$, but to $t \wedge \tau = \min\{t,\tau\}$ which is always bounded and hence everything is legitimate.

Answer (score 4):

If $B^2_t-t^2$ were a local martingale the so too would $t-t^2=(B^2-t)-(B^2-t^2)$ be a (continuous) local martingale, but also a process of finite variation. Such a process must be constant in time, forcing $t-t^2=0$ for all $t>0$, a contradiction. Therefore $B^2_t-t^2$ is no local martingale.

Comment: $\left(B_t^2 - t\right) - \left(B_t^2 - t^2\right) = t^2 - t \neq t - t^2$, but you probably meant $\left(B_t^2 - t^2\right) - \left(B_t^2 - t\right) = t - t^2$.